# What is the Correct usage of Content Modifiers in Snort rule

Tags: snort

I'm new in using Snort and I'm trying to understand Snort rules.

As I was reading Content Modifiers section in snort's manual, it is mentioned that content modifiers should be used **after** a content in rule options

Consider Http Uri:

> As this keyword is a modifier to the previous content keyword, there
> must be a content in the rule before http uri is specified.

But in the latest community rules "snort3-community.rules" , there are rules that have Content modifiers before a content is specified

> alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HTTP_SERVERS $HTTP_PORTS (
> msg:"SERVER-WEBAPP dcboard.cgi invalid user addition attempt";
> flow:to_server,established; **http_uri; content:"/dcboard.cgi";**
> pkt_data; content:"command=register"; content:"%7cadmin";
> metadata:ruleset community; service:http; reference:bugtraq,2728;
> reference:cve,2001-0527; reference:nessus,10583;
> classtype:web-application-attack; sid:817; rev:19; )

I want to know how this rule is interpreted by snort engine and also what is the correct usage of content modifiers

Thanks for your help